# Orientation issue in windows8 metro app.

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am currently working on widows8 metro app tablet version.In My package.appmanifest file I have choose supported rotation as landscape.but when iam launching the applicaiton by holding the device in portrait mode.For fraction of seconds splash screen is coming in portrait mode and then it changed to landscape.

can anyone know how to solve this problem. because of this issue i am facing other issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom splash screen. If your application only supports landscape, you could make your splash screen appear in landscape by manually adjusting the image to load.

Another option could be to make an extended splash screen. This way, you can programatically make your splash screen appear for say, a second or so.

Check this article from Microsoft, [Creating a fast and fluid app launch experience](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/21/creating-a-fast-and-fluid-app-launch-experience.aspx), which has examples and information about extended splash screens.

Comment: I can add the custom splash screen but it will load only when ur app.xaml loads right,one more problem  what is default splash screen u will assign in app manifest file.